Can I produce multiple images with different names/tags from a single docker build with fabric8:docker-maven-plugin
I have a Java project that uses fabric8:docker-maven-plugin to create docker images from multiple different modules.
I have been doing some refactoring which resulted in a need to rename one of the modules that produces a docker image (let's say it was renamed from mycomponent to mycomponent-something). For backwards compatibility reasons, we want to keep producing the mycomponent docker image, but we also want to produce the mycomponent-something docker image. Both of these should be the exact same image and should be tagged the same way (so for version 1.2.3 we'd want to have both myorg/mycomponent:1.2.3 as well as myorg/mycomponent-something:1.2.3.
Is there some way to configure the plugin to do that? Preferably we'd like to build only once and then just retag the resulting image (equivalent of running docker tag myorg/mycomponent-something:1.2.3 myorg/mycomponent:1.2.3)?
I've tried adding multiple  blocks in the plugin configuration:
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
          <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <images>
              <image>
                <name>${docker.registry-name}/${docker.image.org-name}/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
                <build>
                  <labels>
                    <implemented.api.1>Command Router</implemented.api.1>
                  </labels>
                  <ports>
                    <port>5671</port>
                    <port>5672</port>
                    <port>${health.check.port}</port>
                  </ports>
                </build>
              </image>
              <image>
                <!-- also produce a docker image with the legacy name for backwards compatibility -->
                <name>${docker.registry-name}/${docker.image.org-name}/mycomponent:${project.version}</name>
                <build>
                  <labels>
                    <implemented.api.1>Command Router</implemented.api.1>
                  </labels>
                  <ports>
                    <port>5671</port>
                    <port>5672</port>
                    <port>${health.check.port}</port>
                  </ports>
                </build>
              </image>
            </images>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

This produces two images but the first one is the only one that works (is ~300Mb while the second one seems to be empty at ~4.3Mb).
